# Issue during upgrade from sitecore 7.1 to sitecore 7.2 version

Tags: sitecore

We have tried to upgrade Sitecore from version 7.1 to 7.2. We have referenced the following link to upgrade:

URL: http://www.jairosolutions.com/en/Home/Posts/2015/2/Upgrade%20Sitecore%207_1%20IR%20to%207_2%20IR

We have completed some steps, but when we are on "Install the package" step it's not showing success message. We have even waited for 2 days to complete the installation process, but it is showing the following screen:

[image: Update Wizard]

Even though we have tried 2 or 3 times it is still showing the same screen. Please help us.

Comment: In the Sitecore temp folder see <sc.variable name="tempFolder" value="/temp" /> there is log file about the upgrade process. is there a error.

Comment: Try what Jan mentioned here. Look at /temp/__UpgradeHistory/[Build file name]/InstallationLog.txt and InstallationHistory.txt for more clues.These files should have error messages and items the installation had issues on. Also, while this process is running, hit F12 in your browser to bring up developer tools. Look at the Console to see if there were any issues. I've seen connection reset errors when an update to a template was made which had hundreds of dependent items.

Comment: I remember getting something similar, think I had to make some config changes to fix some issues. Just look at the last thing the upgrade wizard was doing to give you some clues or look in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always recommend following official Sitecore documentation for upgrades. The upgrade steps from [sdn.sitecore.net](http://sdn.sitecore.net) mention installing a new version of the update installation wizard. Have you performed this step?

Per sdn.sitecore.net, the steps to follow are:

Upgrade from Sitecore 7.1 initial release:
https://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/Update/7_2_rev_140228/Upgrade_Instructions.aspx

Upgrade from 7.2 to 7.2 SP2:
https://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/Update/7_2_rev_151021.aspx